# Get a part of html form external site

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

How can i get a part of the sorce code of a site for exampel if i would for say to ony want to get this part of code

```
<span class="definition">Anv&#228;nds n&#228;r man s&#228;ger hejd&#229; till n&#229;gon. Ha de G &#228;r samma sak som ha det bra, eller ha det g&#246;tt.</span><br /><br />
```

Form alot of code, and i want to do this in Javascript, and the code is comming from an external site, NAd this is node.js

Comment: So do you know how to fetch a page?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to fetch a partial from another site, but you need to set up an API for the other site that sends the requested element data via AJAX. You are also likely to have CORS issues that you will need to sort out.

Comment: @Korgrue that's not true in this case, he's tagged it 'node.js', which implies that he's looking for non-browser based solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general technique you're talking about is called 'web scraping', and it can range from very simple to very complex.  Assuming you're looking to do this in a node app (as your tags suggest), I'd suggest using the modules `request` and `cheerio`.  If part of the html is generated by clientside javascript, this won't be sufficient, but you didn't indicate that in your question.  Here's a pretty simple code snippet that describes what I'm suggesting:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

request.get('http://example.com/index.html', (err, response, body) => {
   const $ = cheerio.load(body);

   const definitions = $('span.definition');
   console.log(definitions); // these are all selection result elements, you can do more with them here once you see what they contain. 
});
```

Comment: You beat me to it! +1

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I didn't bother with error handling and whatnot, so +1 to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");


request("http://example.com/some-uri", (err, response, body) => {

        if(err)
                throw err; //Handle error


        let $ = cheerio.load(body);

        let myElement = $('span.definition');

        console.log(myElement.html()); //Inner html
        console.log($.html(myElement)); //outer html


});
```